# Is it possible out of stock items should still be able to be purchased in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, shipping-methods

Any idea

Out of stock items should still be able to be purchased and should not be deactivated or the buy button taken away.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of the products which are out of stock and still for sale

Comment: @ASQ Ok wait sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow Backorders

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory
```

Under Product Stock Options

```
Backorders -> Allow Qty Below 0
```

The Product will now need to be set to "In stock" for it to show add to cart buttons